# facebook post no spam link

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i watch 1 youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnsanTdY2Lc and i coding follow them but when i post a link on facebook it not show the photo why? here my code where is wrong point i can't event debug it

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-HJiRD8AiC4k/V_8MznQ6d7I/AAAAAAAADOg/yR2fUN0ja3gPltQ5S_e0NlGZ9gYRzcyyQCLcB/s1600/download.jpg" />

<meta name="googlebot" content="noarchive" />
<meta content="noindex, nofollow" name="robots" />

<meta name="medium" content="image" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<title>Berani yer....akik ni.........-(video inside)</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=uuuuuuuuuuu" />
```

Comment: `og:url` needs to point to the URL of the HTML document you want to share, not the image URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Check your url here([URL debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/)) to make sure you are providing info as expected by Facebook. Like to share image you need to add `og:image` property with meta tag.

Why are you adding following meta?

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=uuuuuuuuuuu" />
```

This will redirect from current url to `uuuuuuuuuuu`